# Creating a grid depending on number of images

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I'm having trouble to figure out how to programatically create a grid dependent of the number of images I have. I can have between 1 and 4 images and it should look like following:

How can i loop this uiimageView?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use UICollectionView for such grid.

There was something like GMGridView: https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView, but it was even discontinued since Apple introduced Collection Views.

Maybe a quick peak at this tutorial will convince you how great Collection Views are: https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started

Good luck!

Comment: i've tried this however since my collectionView is set using constraints i can't seem to get the frame it just return 0 to set the collectionView cell sizes.

Comment: I think you will need to play more with the UICollectionViewFlowLayout, maybe this tutorial will give you some hints: http://zappdesigntemplates.com/create-3-column-grid-view-with-uicollectionview/. If I have more time next month, I will try to play around with this so maybe I can give you more detailed instructions